# Issue with GridSearchCV on a Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

I seem to be getting a really high test error with the following code - am I missing something?

```
numComponents=np.arange(20,220,20)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('norm', StandardScaler()), ('pca',  PCA()), ('lr', LinearRegression())])
gsObj = gridCV(pipe, dict(pca__n_components=numComponents), scoring='mean_squared_error', cv=10, n_jobs=3, pre_dispatch=3)

gsObj.fit(X_train, y_train)
testError=MSE(gsObj.predict(X_test), y_test) # using sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error
```

Even though the lowest CV error comes out to be  170 from the gridSeach, the testError comes out to be 480 (which is huge). The variance of y is 484, so the normalized error `MSE/sigma^2 is ~ 1`.

Is `numComponents` being passed as an array an issue? Should I instead do: `pca__n_components=numComponents.tolist()` in the grid parameters above?

My data set is huge consisting of 675,000 samples with 205 features. The train/test split was 70/30 (used: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cv.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=33`)

Comment: `480` is definitely huge compared to `1e-5`, but it is pretty small compared to `1e7`. Many things are relative. Without any further information all potential helpers here will be lost ...

Comment: How were your training and test splits created? Is there a temporal element to the data?

Comment: Maybe the function you're trying to learn is non-linear. Try fitting to a smaller set. Or maybe your MSE calculation is off, try `sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error`.